# Clicking the table data should take me to the new page and it should fetch the values from the database

Tags: javascript, html

I get a value from my backend,one is departmentid and departments.I display the those two in the table format.If I click the departments it should take me to the new page like departmentid/faculties and it should list all the faculties from that partciular department

result is an object it contains department id and departments.

```js
    function faculites(each_dept) {
      console.log(each_dept);


    }
```

```html
<tbody>
  {% for each_dept in result %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ each_dept.dept_id }}</td>
    <td onclick="faculties(each_dept)" id="dept">{{ each_dept.departments }}</td>

  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I am getting each_dept is not defined in the console log

The expeceted result is:
If I click the department in the table it should take me to the new page 
/deptid/faculties and it should fetch the all the faculty list from the database.
I can handle the database coding ,I need some help with javascript and HTML

Comment: `each_dept` (by which I mean the version mentioned within the tbody) only exists in whatever templating engine you're using (as delimited by `{{` and `}}`) to generate the HTML. It's not a JavaScript variable. I'm not sure (since I don't know this engine - what is it?) but maybe try `onclick="faculties({{ each_dept.dept_id }})"` or something.

Comment: what js framework are you using?